# Accessing second index in 3-d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2-d numpy array that I convert into a 3-d array by using:

```
trainSet = numpy.reshape(trainSet, (trainSet.shape[0], 1, trainSet.shape[1]))
```

My problem is I'm trying to adjust values in the 1st axis (the new one). However, no matter what I try I can not actually figure out how to access the 1's in the new axis. I've tried a multitude of print statements such as

```
print(trainSet[0][0][0])
print(trainSet[1][0][1])
```

but no matter what I try I can not print out any 1's, just the contents of the 2-d array. I know it's a 3d array because when I use

```
print(trainSet.shape)
```

I get

```
(12, 1, 793)
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: You index a 3d array with expressions like `M[i, j, k]`, `M[:, 0, :]`, etc

Answer (score 1):

The one refers to the size of that particular dimension, not the content of the array. The array [[5 5]] has shape (1, 2) but, still, you don't really expect its values must include 1 for that reason, do you?

What inserting a dimension of length one does is increasing the nesting level by one, so a 2d array [[a b] [c d]] will become [[[a b] [c d]]] or [[[a b]] [[c d]]] or [[[a] [b]] [[c] [d]]] depending on where you insert the new axis.

In particular, there are no new elements.

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't mistake your question, what you want is

```
trainSet[:,0,:]
```

Answer (score 0):

the amount of values remains the same, you're just creating a 3D structure instead of the 2D structure.